# debug sftp-server without syslogd

Tags: ssh, logging, sftp

i try to run dropbear ssh server and openSSH sftp-server on uclinux. i need to debug sftp-server program because ls command always return empty directory (file transfer work correctly)!

in this step , i use "dropbear -F -E" instead of using inetd.

i haven't syslogd in my platform and i can't use simple printf for debug because sftp-server call by dropbear using "sh -c" and "execv" function.

(when i run "sftp-server -e" directly , printf output and logs work correctly but sftp-server can't work without ssh server)

anybody can help me how to see printf output or other suggestion about debugging sftp-server.

**Update:**

when i run :
/root # /usr/libexec/sftp-server -e -l VERBOSE >> /mnt/test2.txt

test2.txt file is empty :(

thanks

Comment: Please Comment on this post if my question isn't clear !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i success to debug sftp-server by writing log to text file using fprintf !!!